# Auth Questions / Confusion

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am building a webapp, but I am having some issues and frankly, I'm confused a bit in terms of how things are functioning. I am still learning as I go, making good progress but sometimes I reach a sticking point this one being one.

> **This first portion is solved thanks to @kerbholz**. 
>   I have the main nav-bar with links setup eg. home, create,
>   share. When I click my "homepage" it brings me to the sign up/login
>   view. I don't want that to occur but I rather the logged out user or
>   visitor see the regular homepage with options to register or click the
>   login button to arrive at the login screen.

Need help for the below roadblock.

Secondly, when I create a test user it passes the data to the database, but the test user is not actually logged-in prompting the sign up/login view whenever I visit any page. How can I actually ensure the registered user data is accepted as logged-in?

I hope my questions make sense and any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is below, let me know if anything else is missing.

REPO https://github.com/PT-83/FamiJam

Auth Login page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<? // Hero Section ?>
<div x-data="{ open: false }" class="relative bg-white overflow-hidden">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto ">
    <div class="relative z-10 pb-8 bg-white sm:pb-16 md:pb-20 lg:max-w-2xl lg:w-full lg:pb-28 xl:pb-32">
      <div class="pt-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      </div>

      <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="duration-150 ease-out" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="duration-100 ease-in" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
        <div class="rounded-lg shadow-md">
          <div class="rounded-lg bg-white shadow-xs overflow-hidden">
            <div class="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
              <div>
                <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-white.svg" alt="logo" />
              </div>
              <div class="-mr-2">
                <button @click="open = false" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl px-4 sm:mt-12 sm:px-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-20 lg:px-8 xl:mt-28">
        <div class="sm:text-center lg:text-left">
          <h2 class="text-4xl tracking-tight leading-10 font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl sm:leading-none md:text-6xl">
            Remember Your Family 
            <br class="xl:hidden" />
            <span class="text-indigo-600">Culture & Traditions</span>
          </h2>
          <p class="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 sm:mt-5 sm:text-lg sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto md:mt-5 md:text-xl lg:mx-0">
            Family is important, and so are the stories, homemade recepies, remedies and quality time. Now, there's a simply way to store this information and recall all these special moments.
          </p>
          <p class="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 sm:mt-5 sm:text-lg sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto md:mt-5 md:text-xl lg:mx-0">Famijam is hard at work tyring to complete this application. As progress is being made Famijam is just not ready yet. However, once ready will be sending out beta test oppourtinies to the very first users who registerd. Famijam wants to ensure we are running correctly ensuring stability first and foremost. Thank you!</p>
          <div class="mt-5 sm:mt-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center lg:justify-start">
            <div class="rounded-md shadow">
              <a href="/register" class="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline transition duration-150 ease-in-out md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10">
                Sign up for updates
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 invisible ">
              <a href="#" class="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-700 bg-indigo-100 hover:text-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-50 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline focus:border-indigo-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10">
                Live demo
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <svg class="hidden lg:block absolute right-0 inset-y-0 h-full w-48 text-white transform translate-x-1/2" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="50,0 100,0 50,100 0,100" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg:absolute lg:inset-y-0 lg:right-0 lg:w-1/2">
    <img class="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-97 lg:w-full lg:h-full" src="/images/fun.svg" alt="Photograp" />
  </div>
</div>
<? // End of Hero Section ?>


<? // Features Section ?>
<div class="py-12 bg-white">
    <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="lg:text-center">
        <p class="pt-6 text-base leading-6 text-indigo-600 font-semibold tracking-wide uppercase">Traditions</p>
        <h3 class="mt-2 text-3xl leading-8 font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10">
          Share, Learn, Discuss
        </h3>
        <p class="mt-4 max-w-2xl text-xl leading-7 text-gray-500 lg:mx-auto">
          Now more than ever, a place to document family traditions so they will be remembered!
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-10">
        <ul class="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
          <li>
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 01-9 9m9-9a9 9 0 00-9-9m9 9H3m9 9a9 9 0 01-9-9m9 9c1.657 0 3-4.03 3-9s-1.343-9-3-9m0 18c-1.657 0-3-4.03-3-9s1.343-9 3-9m-9 9a9 9 0 019-9"/>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-4">
                <h5 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Homemade Section</h5>
                <p class="mt-2 text-base leading-6 text-gray-500">
                    Families often make homemade things, this is a great bonding exercise and also a great place to store recipes, how to's, so we can remember and share with each other.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mt-10 md:mt-0">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 6l3 1m0 0l-3 9a5.002 5.002 0 006.001 0M6 7l3 9M6 7l6-2m6 2l3-1m-3 1l-3 9a5.002 5.002 0 006.001 0M18 7l3 9m-3-9l-6-2m0-2v2m0 16V5m0 16H9m3 0h3"/>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-4">
                <h5 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Travel Section</h5>
                <p class="mt-2 text-base leading-6 text-gray-500">
                    Did you travel to visit family, or travel for leisure? If so, did you discover any unique restaurants, try new foods, or unique scenery? If so, share these findings in our travel section.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mt-10 md:mt-0">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 10V3L4 14h7v7l9-11h-7z"/>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-4">
                <h5 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Family Tree</h5>
                <p class="mt-2 text-base leading-6 text-gray-500">
                  Upload photographs of family members with a brief description or story to share with other friends or family.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mt-10 md:mt-0">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-md bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M7 8h10M7 12h4m1 8l-4-4H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-3l-4 4z"/>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ml-4">
                <h5 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Story Time</h5>
                <p class="mt-2 text-base leading-6 text-gray-500">
                  Remember that special moment or story you experienced or were told. Jokes included.
                </p>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
<? // End of Feature Section ---?>

<? // Beginning of CTA ------?>

<div class="bg-white mb-20">
    <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:py-16 lg:px-8 lg:flex lg:items-center lg:justify-around">
      <h2 class="text-3xl leading-9 font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10">
        Ready to Join?
        <br />
        <span class="text-indigo-600">Start sharing, learning, discussing today.</span>
      </h2>
      <div class="mt-8 flex lg:flex-shrink-0 lg:mt-0">
        <div class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
          <a href="/register" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-10 py-4 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
            Get started
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-3 inline-flex rounded-md shadow invisible">
          <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-5 py-3 border border-transparent text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-600 bg-white hover:text-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
            Learn more
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection

@section('footer')

@endsection
```

LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about')->name('about');
Route::get('/contact', 'HomeController@contact')->name('contact');

Route::post('/register/create', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('register');

Route::get('/post/index', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create');
Route::get('/post/{post}', 'PostController@show');
Route::post('/post', 'PostController@store');
```

Comment: fyi, your "web.php" is actually the code for your PostController

Comment: Your `HomeController` uses `$this->middleware('auth');`, every method needs to be auth'd. If you want to exclude your `index` method you can use `$this->middleware('auth')->except(['index']);`

Comment: I would suggest you follow a structured tutorial until you grasp the basic concepts of Laravel.

Comment: @kerbholz thank you, Web.php corrected. Also, when I use the ```->except(['index']);``` that applies to each page? any reason why that's happening?

Comment: @Savlon any suggestions?

Comment: If you do it in your HomeController's `public function __construct()` it will only apply to HomeController

Comment: @kerbholz thanks... super frustrating sometimes, now all my views are showing the same homepage content but shouldn't be ahhhh.

Comment: Because all your routes use the same Controller@Action: `/share', 'HomeController@index` should be `/share', 'HomeController@share` etc. (And `return view ('/share');` should be `return view ('share');` etc)

Comment: @kerbholz omg such a silly mistake... Thank you so much!! Any idea on the second issue (noted in original post)?

Comment: @kerbholz can you post your response as an answer id like to give you the proper credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because all your routes use the same Controller@Action: /share',
>   'HomeController@index should be /share', 'HomeController@share etc.
>   (And return view ('/share'); should be return view ('share'); etc) –
>   kerbholz

The second part regarding the user, laravel takes care of this out of the box. My problem is because I altered the submission form it affected this feature. I will have to play with the form to enable this function to work again. Technically the second portion of the original question is still open, but not necessary to leave this post still unanswered. Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the `$user` you just registered, use `Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);` Then redirect to the view or route you want to.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, would this fall under the RegisteredConroller or LoginController?

Comment: Usually, registration and login are two different jobs and done differently in different controllers. But since you want to log in the user forcefully right after registration, you can write it in the registration controller. Right after you done saving the user.

Comment: Hi Omar, I don't want to force the user to log in after registration per se. Once registered I would like the user to sign in with their registered credentials - when I create the test account it captures my credentials but when I try to log in nothing happens, and the login form just reappears.

Comment: So the problem is with login I guess. I can see you are using laravel default authentication. You might consider doing the login part manually.  This might help you. >https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users